# How to move 4 bytes in a line using vi editor

Tags: vi

I need to move a line by 4 bytes ..How can I do this in the vi editor?

I tried this command - ">>" but that does move more than what I required..I need to specify the parameters to move it only by 4 bytes..

Comment: First, is this an ascii file or binary? Your insistence on a precise 4-bytes makes me wonder.

Answer (score 0):

To shift by spaces in Vi, execute:

```
:set expandtab
```

To shift 4 spaces at a time, execute:

```
:set ts=4
:set sw=4
```

Now when you use `>>` the current line will get 4 spaces added to the front.

The colon puts you on the Vi command line, followed by the set command. This can also be set permanently by editing your ~/.vimrc file. Add:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```